# Is there a setting/extension to default tabs to muted in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, browser-tabs, mute

I'm aware that I can right-click and mute pre-emptively as I open each new tab, but I'd prefer to just not have to worry about it, and in the event I actually want sound, I can re-enable it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Is there a setting/extension to default tabs to muted?

Try [Silent Site Sound Blocker](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/silent-site-sound-blocker/hkbdhiphllimobjnfeeekaogfibmdgfe). "If a site is not on your list and tries to
 play sound, you'll get a prompt which gives you the option of
 whitelisting it forever, allowing the sound once or rejecting it."

> Silent Site Sound Blocker maintains a white list of sites that only
>   you allow to play audio. **If a site is not on your list and tries to
>   play sound, you'll get a prompt which gives you the option of
>   whitelisting it forever, allowing the sound once or rejecting it.**
>
> You can also configure Silent Site to work on a blacklist only model
>   which bans only those sites you designate. Right click the toolbar
>   icon to change modes or instantly blacklist / white list a site.
>   Select "Options" to edit your white and black lists.
>
> Note: You must have Tab audio muting enabled in the Chrome://flags
>   menu. However, for most users this is enabled by default.

Comment: Looks good, but I'm going to give it a week or so of testing before accepting the answer.

Comment: Or, you know, a few months.  Better late than never.

Comment: @Pastymage lol. Thx for the accept :)

Answer (score 1):

Unless I've misunderstood the question, the most straightforward approach is to simply configure the settings for "Default behavior" at `chrome://settings/content/sound` as desired.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote an extension to do this: https://github.com/ludios/mute-new-tabs.  It's also available [in the Chrome Web Store](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/mute-new-tabs/inggmeoccpodpdhmejgmgagmmcdgdkih).